# BigQuery export table to csv file

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to export a BigQuery form UI to Google Storage table but facing this error:

*Errors:
        Table gs://mybucket/delta.csv.gz too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a to shard export. (error code: invalid)*

When trying to export after query I got:

*Download Unavailable This result set contains too many rows to download. Please use "Save as Table" and then export the resulting table.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigQuery can export up to 1 GB of data per file
For larger than 1GB - BigQuery supports exporting to multiple files

See `Single wildcard URI` and `Multiple wildcard URIs` in [Exporting data into one or more files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#exportingmultiple)

Answer (score 13):

Finally found how to do. we must use "*" in the blob name.

[image]

And will create as many file as needed.

[image]

It's weird that i can import large file (~GB) but not possible to export large file :(

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#export_jobs gives a limit of 10Tb per day and 500Gb per export (max 500 parts of 1Gb each)