# Response too large to return while using limit

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

After trying to export result by UI [BigQuery export table to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469903/bigquery-export-table-to-csv-file), now i'm trying to use glcoud command line to do it.

here a snippet:

```
def main(query, file_, max_=1000):
    page = 0
    start = 0
    while True:
        with open(file_, "ab") as fh:
            try:
                query = ("bq query --start_row=%d --max_rows_per_request=%d "
                         "'%s'" % (start, max_, query))
                query_result = subprocess.check_output(query, shell=True)
                fh.write(query_result)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                break
            page += 1
            start = page * max_ + 1
```

But failed, running the first query give my:

[image]

Using  --allow_large_results give me *"BigQuery error in query operation: allow_large_results requires destination_table."* error.

So my question is pretty simple: how to paginate into large table to export the result ?

Answer (score 1):

> how to paginate into large table to export the result?

It looks like your result is greater than 128MB which is the limit above which you have to use destination table to write your result into.  After this done you can export result to GCS as it is outlined in [BigQuery export table to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469903/bigquery-export-table-to-csv-file)

Comment: That I done : query => export to table => export to Google storage => gsutil to download file. For a 1GB table (~ 300MB once gzipped) took me about 45 min to get the result ! :(

Comment: You'r right but still looking for the way to retrieve the entire result whatever the table size. :)